# How does current divide in parallel inductors?

Tags: inductor

How does current divide over parallel inductors?
Take a setup like this, how would I solve for i1, i2 in terms of i?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1UIZm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Think current division in the complex domain. There's still more info needed though. Are you trying to determine a transient, or is this in the steady state?

Comment: I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Okay. Knowing what you're looking for is key in these problems, because each different situation requires a potentially different method.

Comment: But I read that current divides through capacitors in parallel exactly like voltage divides over resistors in series. I thought there might be a similar principle here.

Comment: My professor was talking about voltage division along series capacitors is the ratio of the capacatance. He said a similar principle existed for inductors in parallel.

Comment: For the steady state, we need some nonzero series resistance. Ideal inductors have no resistance, so they are short circuits to DC. Current rises higher and higher without bound.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Lets start by putting down what we know

[image]

The voltage across each inductor must be the same (just like the current must be the same to series capacitors).
Now the voltage induced in an inductor is

$$V = L \frac{\mathrm{d}i}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

These voltages must be equal so that

$$ V_{AB}
= L_1 \frac{\mathrm{d}(i_1)}{\mathrm{d}t}
= L_2 \frac{\mathrm{d}(i_2)}{\mathrm{d}t} $$

If we integrate with respect to t (\$L_1\$ and \$L_2\$ are constants) we get

$$ L_1 i_1  =  L_2 i_2 $$

so the ratio of currents is

$$ \frac{i_1}{i_2} = \frac{L_2}{L_1} = \frac{2}{1} $$

In other word the biggest current will flow in the smallest inductor (*just like the biggest voltage drop will be across the smallest capacitor in a series circuit*).

If you were to treat the inductance values as if they were "resistance values"  (which they are not) you would see immediately that "the bigger resistance" would take less current and it would be in the ratio of the "resistances"

To obtain the current \$i\$ combine the inductance values

$$ \frac{1}{L} = \frac{1}{L_1} + \frac{1}{L_2} $$

so that the circuit is reduced to a single inductor \$L = \frac{2}{3} H\$

then use kirchoff's law \$ i = i_1  + i_2\$

and as you already know \$ i1 = 2 \cdot i_2 \$

you have everything you need to work it out.

Comment: I can't make the edit since it's only 1 character, but should be L2/L1 for the ratio after integration. (as opposed to L2/L2)

Comment: @DanielBall thanks for that Daniel - my original answer had been edited for the maths notation and that small error had crept in - good catch.

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to make this complicated.  Each inductor with the same voltage applied to it, whether AC or a complicated waveform or not, will have current thru it inversely proportional to its inductance relative to the other inductors.  This is just like parallel resistors have relative current thru them inversely proportional to their resistance.  The same formula as for parallel resistance can be used to determine inductor current sharing.

For example, consider two ideal inductors in parallel, a 10 µH and a 30 µH, both starting with 0 current.  The current thru the 10 µH inductor will always be 3x the current thru the 30 µH inductor.  You don't need to know anything about the magnitude or waveshape of the voltage to make this statement.

Answer (score 2):

Transform the inductance values to impedance values - there are well known equations for this.

Once you have the impedance values it should be easier to see where the current flows : since this is a parallel circuit, more current flows through the lower impedance.

Answer (score 0):

You would find the currents of the inductors by simply using current division. I had a similar problem where I had a current source of 25mA and two parallel inductors the first of 60mA and the second of 40mA. the answers using current division were the same as in the back of my book which lead me to believe that you can. I am not entirely sure though, just thought this may help since it worked for me in a previous problem.